# Storing Categorical from codes from Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe enumerated for each 50 rows they interpolate between A and B. I don't really understand the function Categorical.from_codes. I have a dataframe that holds my features that are simply 20 pixels from 50 images, therefore a matrix of 50x20. The Y values are simply the index values for instance: pixel 0, 1, 2, 3 and forth. This is my dataframe and its enumeration, how for given dataframe, can i extract X and Y, where X is my data, Y should be my categories.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_array = np.zeros((700, 20))
indices = sorted(list(range(0,int(my_array.shape[0]/50)))*50)
pixel_index = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

df = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns=pixel_index)

class_names = list('AB')
target_names = ["Class_" + c for c in class_names]
n_sets = df.shape[0]//50
class_col = []
for name in target_names:
    class_col += [name]*50
n_sets = df.shape[0]//(50*len(target_names))
class_col = class_col*n_sets
df['class'] = class_col
X = pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns= pixel_index)
y = pd.Categorical.from_codes(indices,target_names)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because 'indices' contains more categories (0-13) than there are in 'target_names' (2)

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: I want to store Categorical.from_codes inside Y.

Comment: What would you like these codes to be? It seems like you're generating fake data.

Comment: They aren't fake data, they're reproducible data. X works fine, but i get errors when trying to use pd.Categorical.from_codes, it says it should have array like values between -1 and 1, which i simply fail to understand how exactly my categories should be like that.

Comment: When i print target_names im expecting an output like this: array(['class_A', 'class_B']) where indices needs to be simply the target.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to create a Y series which is 0/1, corresponding to the class you create for every row, replace this line:

```
y = pd.Categorical.from_codes(indices,target_names)
```

With

```
y = pd.Categorical(df["class"]).codes
```

The value of y would then be 50 zeros, 50 1's, 50 zeros, 50 1's, etc.

Comment: Actually, i'm doing classification using some sort of LDA. I have only class A and B true or false, which is a recognition job. Therefore i am enumerating each 50 rows for instance 1-50 is true, 51-100 false, 101-150, true, 151-200 false and forth.

Comment: Well, that's not what you're doing. If what you're looking for is a way to have 50 true, then 50 false, then 50 true, etc - you should probably clarify that in the question.

Comment: It is what i am doing, try doing df.head(51) the 51th element is B. Also, that isn't the problem,  the problem is that if i do Y = df['class']  or Y = target_names, i will get errors.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't exactly what i was trying to do